# Node promises and catch issue

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am currently writing a database class that receives a node http request and saves data into a db.

It uses MSSQL (yeah...), therefore I'm using node-mssql.

I created a class to manage DB access, code:

```
"use strict";
var config = require('../../config/mainConfigs');
const mssql = require('mssql');

class db {

    constructor(){
        this._pool = null;
    }

    get_pool(){

        if (!this._pool) {

            if (config.Logging.DB.type == 'mssql'){

                const dbOptions = {
                    user: config.Logging.DB.user,
                    password: config.Logging.DB.password,
                    server: config.Logging.DB.mssql.server,
                    database: config.Logging.DB.mssql.database,
                    options: {
                        encrypt: config.Logging.DB.encrypt
                    }
                };

                this._pool = new mssql.ConnectionPool(dbOptions);

            }
        }

        return this._pool;

    }

    insertHTTPRequest(req){

    const pool = this.get_pool();

    if (config.Logging.DB.type == 'mssql'){

        if (pool._connected){

            var request = new mssql.Request(pool);

            var query = `INSERT INTO SD_LOG (
                MODULE, 
                INSTANCE, 
                REMOTE_ADDR, 
                USERNAME, 
                USER_AGENT, 
                HTTP_METHOD, 
                HTTP_REQ_URL
            ) OUTPUT Inserted.ID_SD_LOG VALUES (
                @module,
                @instance,
                @remote_addr,
                @username,
                @user_agent,
                @http_method,
                @http_req_url
            )`;

            request.input('module', 'tokenizer');
            request.input('instance', config.Deployment.instance);
            request.input('remote_addr', req.ip);
            request.input('username', req.user.displayName);
            request.input('user_agent', req.headers['user-agent']);
            request.input('http_method', req.method);
            request.input('http_req_url', req.url);

            return request.query(query);


        }else{

            return pool.connect().then(() => {
                var request = new mssql.Request(pool);

                var query = `INSERT INTO SD_LOG (
                    MODULE, 
                    INSTANCE, 
                    REMOTE_ADDR, 
                    USERNAME, 
                    USER_AGENT, 
                    HTTP_METHOD, 
                    HTTP_REQ_URL
                ) OUTPUT Inserted.ID_SD_LOG VALUES (
                    @module,
                    @instance,
                    @remote_addr,
                    @username,
                    @user_agent,
                    @http_method,
                    @http_req_url
                )`;

                request.input('module', 'tokenizer');
                request.input('instance', config.Deployment.instance);
                request.input('remote_addr', req.ip);
                request.input('username', req.user.displayName);
                request.input('user_agent', req.headers['user-agent']);
                request.input('http_method', req.method);
                request.input('http_req_url', req.url);

                request.query(query);

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I am using a middleware in the routes to save the request into the DB, like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    //send req to DB, get ID_SD_LOG from DB, assign to req.id
    db_instance.insertHTTPRequest(req).then((genid)=>{
        req.id = genid;
        next();
    }).catch((err)=>{
        combinedLogger.error(err);
        res.send('Database is unavailable.');
        res.end();
    })
});
```

Thing is, I am getting an error, however, in console, the error is undefined. So I really can't figure out whats wrong. I can imagine it's the connect() method, as I tested logging in console static string in the db request and I don't them, which I assume it's not even accessing that part.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: I looked at this and the source of the error didn't jump out at my, but you definitely have an anti-pattern in the code. There's no need to wrap a function that returns a promise in another promise. Just return the first promise.

Comment: @Mark_M I edited the question taking off the anti-pattern. I am still getting error undefined...

Comment: I managed to find WHERE is the issue, and I found that it's in the following line:  request.input('username', mssql.NVarChar, req.user.displayName); as user.displayName is not in the req, therefore its undefined. HOWEVER, using something like if(typeof req.user.displayName == "undefined") to add that parameter or not doesn't work either...